# I am not able to count the words in a string

Tags: c, string

```
int FindWords(char *str)
{
    int i, word = 1;

    for (i = 0 ; *(str + i)! = '\0'; i++) {
        if (isspace(*str + i)) {
            if (isspace(*str + i + 1)) {
                continue;
            }
            word++;
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

I am not able to count words in a string. I googled the `isspace()` function.

Comment: so step through the code in a debugger, or print out the values in the loops to see what they are to understand the behavior,

Comment: Use `str[i]`; it's easier.  If you must explicitly dereference a pointer, use parentheses: `*(str + i)`.

Comment: @Landstalker That's hard to define ;-).

Comment: @yakoudbz Why? I think the OP tries to skip over an unknown number of whitespace.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, Ha yes, I read too fast

Comment: You must understend that `*str + i + 1` is not `*(str + i + 1)`. Start by correcting that first. This writing `*str + i + 1` is false.

Comment: `*str + i` is not the same of `*(str + i)`. The first one add `i` to the `str` content's (not the address). The second, adds `i` to `str` address's and then obtain its content.

Comment: different is `!=` and not `! =`

Comment: Ehm, strtok anyone?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ehm, suppose it is an exercise to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int FindWords(char *str) {
     int i = 0, length = 0, word = 0;

     length = strlen(str);

     for (i = 1 ; i < length; i++) {
         if (str[i] == ' ' && str[i-1] != ' ') {
             word++;
         }
     }

     if ( strlen(str)> 0) {
        if (str[length-1] != ' '){
            word++;
        }
     }

     return word;
 }
```

I would do like that. looping all the characters in the string, and each time we fall on a space and that the character before is not a space, it means we just finished a new word so we increment word. We also increment word at the very end if the last character is not a space.

strlen(str) Gives me the number of characters in the str string.

Comment: FindWords for ""  = ?!

Comment: what about \r and \t and other white space characters?
' '   (0x20) space (SPC)
'\t' (0x09) horizontal tab (TAB)
'\n' (0x0a) newline (LF)
'\v' (0x0b) vertical tab (VT)
'\f' (0x0c) feed (FF)
'\r' (0x0d) carriage return (CR)

Comment: Thanks @Landstalker, I forgot that case, it's corrected

Comment: @OwaisQureshi, It will require a longer code to take all the cases in consideration, or maybe a function already exists, i don't know. I just took the case of a plain paragraph.

Comment: @BabyFrost `FindWords` for `NULL` ptr = ?!

Comment: This code will work only when there is no leading or traing space. `str[length]` is `'\0'` by definition, so the last `if` is always true. If you have spaces at the end, `str[i] == ' ' && str[i+1] != ' '` will be true, because you test the terminating null character again. And you miss the first word if there are no leading spaces. (Your last `if` is supposed to fix that I guess, but you should check `str[0]` and make sure that `str` isn't the empty string.)

Comment: Hm. The new code is more complicated, but it still isn't correct. [See here](https://ideone.com/h0OdNU) for a straightforward and working solution. (You can run the test strings there on your code and see how it works out.)

Comment: Thanks @MOehm, now it works just just fine, should have done backward comparism instead of forward. Thanks. Your code is awesome, I want that level some day.

Comment: Yes, that's better. Thanks for fixing it. (Well, I'm blushing. "Awesome" is perhaps a bit much ...)

Comment: `char *pcString = NULL; FindWords (pcString);` crash your program ...

Answer (score 0):

```
int FindWords(char *str)
{
   int i,word=1;

    for(i=0;str[i];i++)
    {
      if(isspace(str[i]))
       {
    if(isspace(str[i+1]))
    {
    continue;
    }
    word++;
       }
    }
    return word;
}
```

I ended up with this.but still not quite reliable! 
logic is the same as in question but took some advice from comments!

Comment: What's `j` for? If you start with a count of 1, you will be wrong when the string is empty or has only spaces. You are also miscounting the words when you have spaces at the beginning or at the end.